# Execution of frontend tests in embedded webapp

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

In our setup we are building and deploying our UI5 app as an embedded static resource within our Spring boot maven-based application. During the CI build with the SAP Cloud SDK pipeline, the frontent tests are however not being executed.

Looking at the pipeline code, it seems to me that those stages are only executed for HTML5 modules and not for Java modules. However, the npm modules should be available as they are collected during initialization stage as far as I can see.

So the question for me is if there is a way to execute the frontend tests also in this scenario or if not, whether this intentionally not being done due to other constraints I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For projects using MTA/Cloud Application Programming Model this is correct. Currently, we expect only html5 modules to contain frontends and the corresponding tests. Reason for that is that MTA brings that structure by default and there were no other request for this yet. However, as it also looks like a valid setup we will discuss whether we implement that in one of the future releases. You are also invited to create pull requests.

If you are using a plain maven project generated with the SAP Cloud SDK, you can have this setup of having the frontend embedded into the webapp folder. In this case, you only need to configure the npm script `ci-frontend-unit-test` in your package.json in the root of the project.